# can get 2 cherrypy instance working simultaneously - sessions are not independent

Tags: session, cherrypy

I have two copy of the same program (a stable version and a dev version) on the same computer. They are located in different directories. They listen to different ports (8080 and 8081). In both, i use sessions to store information relative to the current session with

> cherrypy.session['some_key'] = 'some_value'

I read this information with

> cherrypy.session.get('some_key')

The porgram works perfectly, when i have only one instance.

The problem comes when i try to let both instances run. It looks like, the sessions  are somehow not independent:

- Start both program
- do something in program 1 (in browser, on port 8080), which fills the session variable
- do something in program 2, which fills also the session variables
- go back to program 1 -> the session is not valid anymore: `cherrypy.session.get('some_key')` is `None`

I tried with session stored in ram or in a file, the problem is the same.

Any idea is welcome...

Comment: How are you accessing your sites in the browser?

Comment: through  server.com:8080/app1 and server.com:8081/app2

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering has to do with the fact that your browser assigns cookies by either domain name or ip.  Since you're accessing your site with the same ip, doesn't matter that there are different ports.  To test this theory store different session values in each site then access both sites and check your cookie.  If both values are there that would be your problem.

You may be able to assign a domain name to each site's ip with the port in your hosts file.  Then the cookies should be different.

```
192.168.0.154:8080  www.abc.com
192.168.0.154:8181  www.def.com
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, first bad news :) But i've heard, that cookies could also store the full path (and not only the DN). In my case, both apps are accessed through diffent pathes : server.com:8080/app1 and server.com:8081/app2. Can one settle this with cherrypy ?

Comment: open up your browser's cookie files and see if you get two different cookies.  I suspect you don't.

Comment: yes, only one cookie is stored and used by browser, with the name session_id, and nothing stored in  the "path" field. Therefore, i'm wondering if 1) could change the name of the cookie  and 2) if one could set the path.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to throw another network card in there and assign your 2nd app a different IP.

Comment: I can't do that. I'm in a network, with no admin rights :) (not at home ! ;) )

Comment: for the name of the cookie, i would bet on "tools.sessions.name" ... i have to try

Comment: The name is just name of the directory where the session files will be stored.  I tested with two sites on the same ip and they kept overwriting the other's cookie.

Comment: no, it's not !! I've just tested it ! The name of the directory is set by tools.sessions.storage_path... maybe we have different version of cherrypy ?

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Kloos explained, the browser assigns cookies by either domain name or ip. If two my programs run on the same machine, and there is on the client side only one cookie shared by both programs. 
One solution is to give different names to the cookies. The default name given by the session module of cherry is 'session_id'. To set a different name, one can do this in the section [/] of the cherrypy config file:

```
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.sessions.storage_type = file
tools.sessions.storage_path = some_path
tools.sessions.name = some_cookie_name
```

(thanks to Andrew Kloos)